# How to convert character set in Java?

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

```
SftpFile agencyFile = (SftpFile)agencyiter.next();

LOGGER.info(" agencyFile.getAbsolutePath() "+ agencyFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Output:**

```
agencyFile.getAbsolutePath() /Agency_Ja????n
```

In my above code I am getting the `agencyFile.getAbsolutePath()` as with special characters like `???`.

How can I avoid them?

I tried also the following code, but got the same output.

```
byte[] ptext = agencyFile.getAbsolutePath().getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
String value = new String(ptext, UTF_8);
```

Comment: How do you check the output? Is it printed to the console or to a file?

Comment: it is printed in console and files also

Comment: Then the problem is most likely that your console can't print that character, Your original code should work fine.

Comment: Print you output to a file and use `NotePad++` to view it. Also, Read up on the character encoding of the input file. If you are using `Windows` OS, see what happens if you convert the bytes to `Windows 1252` encoding.

Comment: I have exported into a file, still the same output is coming

Comment: did you try using [common's StringUtil class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/StringUtils.html)?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are within java you need not bother about the character encoding of a string. You only have to bother if your string crosses the border of your java application to the outside world, as serialized byte array (file content, socket stream etc.), called I/O.

Does your `ptext` already contain the value 0x3F (which is the byte code of `?`)?

If yes, then your problem occured already when constructing the SftpFile instance. Debug that code spot and verify what is entered as path of your file instance (and where it comes from).

If no: There is a character which cannot be printed by your console or file viewer. Configure your Logger to write UTF-8 output. Then every usual editor (as Notepad++, UltraEdit, etc.) can display it. Of course also your OS must have installed the respective font.